# GraphQL Mutation Body Parser

Tags: curl, post, graphql, express-graphql

Just updated to 'graphql-server-express' version 1.3.0 and now I am getting this error when running any mutations:

```
POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?
```

When initializing the server, I am including the "body-parser" package so I am not sure what is going on here.  Any ideas?

Server Config:

```
    //GraphQL Server
    graphQLServer.use(

        //GRAPHQL Endpoint
        `/${settings.public.graphql.endpoint}`,

        //Parse JSON
        bodyParser.json(),

        //authenticate
        authenticateRequest,

        //GRAPHQL Server
        graphqlExpress(req => {

            return {
                schema: schema,
                context: req
            }
        })

    );
```

Example Request:

```
curl 'http://localhost:5050/graphql' \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -d '{
    "query": "mutation { sensorData(sensorValue: \u0027asdasdasdasd \u0027)}",
    "variables": {}
    }
  }'
```

Answer (score 8):

Set `Content-Type: application/json` header in the request ([docs](http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request))

```
curl 'http://localhost:5050/graphql' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -d '{
    "query": "mutation { sensorData(sensorValue: \u0027asdasdasdasd \u0027)}",
    "variables": {}
    }
  }'
```

Comment: Thanks Bless!  Adding the Content-Type worked for me.  Appreciate your input :)